# StyleCop, messages for a file only?

Tags: stylecop

I started using stylecop, for new project it's working out fine when we are checking for warnings as we write.

But for existing projects where there are hundreds of warnings, it's not even usable as it's almost impossible to see warnings only on that file.

**Is there any way i can see warning for file i am running stylecop on?**

Comment: Are you using StyleCop from within Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, using studio stylecop plugin. Also hundreds of warning i mentioned are not stylecop but our mess, but stylecop warnings are blended together.

Comment: I would suggest limiting the amount of rules that StyleCop enforces so that you don't get many violations at once. You can then increase the amount of enforced rules when you resolve the violations found.

Answer (score 1):

In VisualStudio you should be able to right click the open file (editor) and select the popup menu entry *Run StyleCop*. Then StyleCop should only check this current file.